# Swift 4 Как создать область для перетаскивания приложения и кастомные кнопки закрытия?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

Вот так выглядит с включенным Title Bar. За сам Бар, собственно, приложение и перетаскивается, оттуда же его можно свернуть и закрыть. 
Мне нужно, чтобы дизайн приложения был полностью плоским, то есть без этого самого бара.

Первой проблемой стало то, что я не смог нагуглить как добавить сами кнопки закрытия\сворачивания куда-либо кроме бара. 
Решил с помощью нарисованных своей рукой изображений, висящих на кнопках.

Вторая проблема в том, что при выключении Title Bar приложение перестает быть прозрачным. На последнем скрине это очень хорошо видно.

Третья проблема в том, что я не могу перетащить приложение, оно и понятно, зоны для перетаскивания ведь нет.

Прошу подтолкнуть на верный путь!

[image: Title Bar включен]

[image: Title Bar выключен]
[image: Title Bar выключен]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Кнопки никуда переместить нельзя, они всегда будут в левом верхнем углу. Ты конечно можешь их скрыть совсем и сделать свои кастомные, где угодно.

2) Можешь не выключать TitleBar, а просто скрыть его Title. Достаточно выбрать Hide Title.
[image: Достаточно выбрать Hide title]

3) У WindowController твоего окна, в методе windowDidLoad() необходимо указать `window?.isMovableByWindowBackground = true`

Comment: У меня нет такой опции "Hide Title". Сразу идет поле Autosave

Comment: Тогда в методе windowDidLoad() в NSWindowController вашего окна можно написать window?.titleVisibility = .hidden